# Update products without category

Tags: mysql, category

I can get all products that doesn't have category with this query, how can I update them with an category id considering this query to select:

```
   SELECT e.entity_id,e.sku
FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS l ON l.product_id = e.entity_id
WHERE l.category_id IS NULL
```

I need to set

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_product` SET l.category_id = '132' WHERE l.category_id IS NULL
```

SQLFIDDLE:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59b01/2

Comment: What error msg are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Your query seem correct, but since you update query seem to not be using an primary key you need to using `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES`

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

update catalog_category_product AS l LEFT JOIN 
  catalog_product_entity AS e ON l.product_id = e.entity_id 
    SET l.category_id = '132
WHERE l.category_id IS NULL; 

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

or

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

update catalog_category_product AS l  
  SET l.category_id = '132
WHERE l.category_id IS NULL;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Comment: Hmm I got SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).


update catalog_category_product AS l LEFT JOIN 
  catalog_product_entity AS e ON l.product_id = e.entity_id 
    SET l.category_id = '132'
WHERE l.category_id IS NULL;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
 

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: here is them fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5fd3/1

Comment: Also sql_safe_updates is OFF

Comment: Your orginal select query return zero result, so nothing to update

Comment: Also you have create statement (if not exist) for `catalog_category_product` twice. Which table structure do you want to use

Comment: HMM it looks like it doesn't update, it inserts because on catalog_category_product I dont have any product with category_id NULL, this is strange they way select query works. I have updated sqlfiddle.

Comment: The url should have change, can you post the latest url

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59b01/2

Comment: It look the same ... and still creating the first which PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`product_id`), so category_id can never be null

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using LOST PRODUCT Extension instead.

http://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-lost-products.html